# IBrokers R package: issue with class twsconn (R)

Tags: r, ibrokers

At the moment, I am switching from Python to R and I am trying to write some simple code to price a portfolio, using Jeff Ryan's Ibrokers package. I would like to have a field of class `twsconn` in one of my objects

```
setClass( "MktAsset",
  representation( IB.id = "character",
                          asset.type = "factor",
              ccy = "factor",
              IB.conn = "twsconn") )
```

but the system does not seem happy about it

Msg is

> In .completeClassSlots(ClassDef, where) :
>     undefined slot classes in definition of "MktAsset": IB.connection(class "twsconn")

but when I ask the class of tws (initialized with `tws <- twsConnect()`, it returns

```
[1] "twsconn"     "environment"
```

I tried to go through the code to check for the existence of a class `twsconn` but, I found nothing.

Can someone help?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'd ask on `r-sig-finance` instead as Jeff reads that.

Comment: @Dirk: now you're helping people cross-post?  What's this world coming to? ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is S3 in S4.  This should work:

```
setOldClass("twsconn")  # this is what you are missing
setClass( "MktAsset",
  representation( IB.id = "character",
                     asset.type = "factor",
         ccy = "factor",
         IB.conn = "twsconn") )

# [1] "MktAsset"

a <- new("MktAsset")

ibg <- ibgConnect() # connect to IB Gateway

a@IB.conn <- ibg
a

An object of class "MktAsset"
Slot "IB.id":
character(0)

Slot "asset.type":
factor(0)
Levels:

Slot "ccy":
factor(0)
Levels:

Slot "IB.conn":
<twsConnection,1 @ 20110325 13:15:22 CST, nextId=1>
```

If you're able to come to R/Finance in Chicago in April [www.RinFinance.com](http://www.RinFinance.com), I'll be doing a two-hour workshop on Friday 
morning (April 29th) regarding IBrokers (and algorithmic trading in general with R)
that would be of interest I suspect.